# wkhtmltopdf converting the current state of html page to pdf?

Tags: php, html, pdf, wkhtmltopdf

Html to pdf is happening on local server through php and offering the html file as pdf for download is working fine, the html page I'm passing to wkhtmltopdf is a filled with user input then I need to convert
it into pdf but it converts the blank form_1.html which I've placed in my web server directory.

How can i get pdf of currently open html page of named form_1.htm.

Is there anything HTTP_REFERER i need to use here.

```
<?php
//Passing form_1.htm page prints the black form html page I want to print it after it opens in browser with filled user's input.
$result = shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe" form_1.htm vish.pdf 2>> err3.txt 1>> out3.txt');
echo $result;
$file = "vish.pdf";
$pdf = file_get_contents("vish.pdf");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdf));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($file).'";');
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
echo $pdf;
?>
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<p>Karna' wife!</p>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You won't be able to capture the information the user has entered in the form by printing that way.

To generate a PDF of it you would need to save the data to the server, then get wkhtmltopdf to request a page which had the form filled with the details from the form.

The reason for this is due to the stateless nature of HTTP which is used to serve the HTML page.

When the user request form_1.html they get sent the HTML page, they fill in the form details, but all that information is stored locally on their computer.

If someone else request form_1.html they get sent another copy of the HTML page, without any of the details, as the web server as yet knows nothing of the details the first user entered.

The server only finds out the content of the first users form when the user submits the form to the server. The server application can then decide what to do with it.

If you consider that wkhtmltopdf works just like another user with a web browser you'll see why they only ever receive the form.

If you want to go the wkhtmlpdf route then you will need to

1. Save the submitted data locally on the server
2. Set up a second HTML page that can be requested with the ability to load that specific date
3. set wkhtmltopdf up to request that web page
4. send the resultant file to the user

If you want to send the USER a PDF version of what they enter into the form without saving it a better approach may be to process the submitted form data using PHP and to use a server side PDF generation tool, such as http://www.tcpdf.org or http://www.fpdf.org/ , to create a PDF and send it to the user. It wouldn't look like their form, but it would produce a PDF for them.

**EDIT:** more detail on an approach to do this via wkhtmltopdf (note this is not very secure)

Given this html form (form_1.html)

```
<html>
<body>
<form method="post" action="respond.php">
   <input type="text" name="fieldname">
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

In your php that is responding to the form post, let's call it 'respond.php'

```
<?php 

$form_values = $_POST;

// you should really validate $form_values
$contents = serialize($form_values);
$filename = sha1($contents);
file_put_contents($filename,$contents);

$result = shell_exec('"C:\\Program Files\\wkhtmltopdf\\bin\\wkhtmltopdf.exe" http://localhost/get.php?filename='+$filename+' vish.pdf 2>> err3.txt 1>> out3.txt');
echo $result;
$file = "vish.pdf";
$pdf = file_get_contents("vish.pdf");

header('Content-Type: application/pdf');
header('Cache-Control: public, must-revalidate, max-age=0'); // HTTP/1.1
header('Pragma: public');
header('Expires: Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT'); // Date in the past
header('Last-Modified: '.gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s').' GMT');
header('Content-Length: '.strlen($pdf));
header('Content-Disposition: inline; filename="'.basename($file).'";');
ob_clean(); 
flush(); 
echo $pdf;
exit()
```

in get.php (which needs to be accessible via a web server)

```
<?php

$filename = $_GET['filename']

// you should really validate $filename

$contents = file_get_contents($filename);
$form_values = unserialize($contents);

?>
<html>
<body>
<form>
<input type="text" name="fieldname" value="<?php print $form_values['fieldname'] ;?>">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

The key thing being you need to get wkhtmltopdf to receive an HTML page which has the form fields filled out by the server. So when wkhtmltopdf requests `http://localhost/get.php?filename='+$filename+'`it receives and HTML page from your localhost which has all of the form details filled out on it.

**Please note that this is a conceptual solution, to illustrate how you use it. I wouldn't recommend this in production, as it relies on security through obscurity**

Comment: using tcpdf and fpdf I need to write lots of code to get things done, I'm looking for wkhtmltopdf example.

Comment: You'll have to write lots of code for it to work with wkhtmltopdf as you'll need to store the data locally to your server then get wkhtmltopdf to load it.

Comment: that would be easier compared to tcpdf and fpdf where I need write code to generate complex html to pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass all the form parameters and regenerate the form before you pass it to wkhtmltopdf, like DorianFM describes (+1).

Another option may be to use a service, that does this for you like http://www.pdfmyform.com